# How to access start and search keys programmatically in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8, state

I want to disable the start and search keys in windows phone.

I want to retrieve the last page or last state for the application when i click my application icon after press start key on the device. If it is Possible or not.

Please Help Me. Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should look into the following:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967548(v=vs.105).aspx

This link sounds like it might answer some of your questions. You cannot disable the hardware start and search buttons.